# The Ads display screen still restricts the ads to 220px

Tags: bug, status-completed

Out of curiosity I clicked on the link to view the ads: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2436

The first thing I noticed was they all looked squished. I confirmed in my browser that they are being limited to 220px wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more details check out [the related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273089/301021) on Meta.

The gist is that the code is shared between the demo area and the sidebar. As such they were unable to update the size of one without affecting the other. It was the lesser of two evils to leave the ads in the demo area squished.

Comment: You are correct. I've left a comment in the code so hopefully there won't be a mixup between us developers again before the new round of ads goes out. Thanks for being patient.

Answer (score 4):

You're entirely correct; an oversight. Fixed next deploy, thanks.

Comment: Actually, not an oversight. I had to revert this back again for the reason the OP already discovered and wrote in his answer. It'll be fixed when the new round of community ads go live... or if some overly-ambitious dev decides to build a workaround in the meantime that fixes the stats page for the new ads _without_ breaking the old ones.

Comment: @BretCopeland ah, sorry! oops!